# Automatic Initialization of subclass in superclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance

A similar question was asked in [Initialize subclass within class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31387342/3854633). The answers there concluded that this kind of approach should be avoided, I am not sure if this is true for the following case, and I would like to know either how it can be achieved, or what I should do instead.

```py
class Rational():
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        if self.denominator == 1:
            pass
            # >>> How to initialize as Integer in this case? <<<

    # ... More methods for rationals


class Integer(Rational):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__(value, 1)
        self.value = value

    # ... More methods for integers
```

In this file, I have simple classes for Integer and `Rational` numbers. Since all `Integer`s are rational, `Integer` is a subclass of rational, and we call `super()` to allow methods for rational numbers to be called by the integer.

It would be nice though, if whenever a `Rational` was initialized with denominator 1, it could be automatically recognized as an integer. For example, I would want `x = Rational(4, 1)` to then allow me to call `x.integer_method()` or even have `Integer(4) == x` return True. The trouble is, I don't know if I can call the `Integer` initializer from the `Rational` initializer because I may be caught in an infinite loop.

What is the best way to resolve this (in a general way that works not just for integers and rationals, but for any Parent-Child type where an instance of Parent might not be recognized as semantically equivalent to a member of Child type until initialization time?

Comment: Sounds like a textbook usecase for a factory method for replacing the constructor.

Comment: If you define a `__new__()` method for the `Rational` class, it can return an instance of `Integer` when the conditions are met. See my answer to the question [Improper use of \__new__ to generate classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035685/improper-use-of-new-to-generate-classes) for an example.

Comment: Poor design pattern, not very SoLID

Comment: @Pynchia: Not the greatest comment because it assumes everyone knows what [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__new__` to define how the class is constructed, including constructing other classes. Avoid defining `__init__`, since it is not automatically called when `__new__` returns an object of another type. As this scheme strongly couples classes together, `Integer` can avoid calling `super().__new__` for simplicity.

```
class Rational():
    def __new__(cls, numerator, denominator=1):
        if denominator == 1:
            return Integer(numerator)
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        return self   # new always returns an instance

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Rational({self.numerator}/{self.denominator})'

class Integer(Rational):
    denominator = 1  # as a Rational, Integer must expose numerator and denominator
    def __new__(cls, value):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.numerator = value
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Integer({self.numerator})'
```

This is enough to dynamically construct the appropriate subclass:

```
>>> Rational(12, 3)
Rational(12/3)
>>> Rational(15, 1)
Integer(15)
```

Ideally, such classes should be immutable; otherwise, `Integer` being a `Rational` implies that `some_integer.denominator = 3` is valid and produces a `Rational` with 1/3 the initial value.